# Check if SecTrustedApplicationRef is a trusted app for a SecKeychainItemRef

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, keychain

I'm trying to go through the keychain and get a list of the Internet Password keychain items that my application has full access to (e.g. won't be prompted).  How can i determine that from a SecKeychainItemRef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `SecKeychainSetUserInteractionAllowed` to temporarily disable prompting. With prompts off, you can simply list all passwords and try to get the data of each one. The ones that succeed are the ones you can access.